# Multiple SSL certificates under one organization?

Tags: security, https

Now that I have my LLC formed, I intend to purchase several EV SSL certificates for a few of my popular online stores. My question is if it is possible to purchase and set up several EV SSL certificates for different domains / sites that all proclaim to be JohnDoe LLC?

Or is JohnDoe LLC allowed to have only ONE EV SSL cert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EV SSL certificates require extensive validation and the processes used to do this differ depending on the company issuign them. However, these validation steps are to prove 2 things.

1) You represent a genuine company and that you have the authority to respresent the company.

2) That the company you are acting on behalf of owns the domain name in question.

As such, no there will not be a limitation to the number of EV SSL certificates that any company can own - you can purchase an EV SSL certificate for every domain name that the company owns, if you wish.

I hope this helps.